# Can we lose items from chest during Goblin Attack?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, I'm keeping my server open 24x7. Yesterday, I was unable to play and when I joined in today I noticed that all the money I stored in one of the chest is gone(had around 60 gold coins).

I asked other players about this and they said that there was a goblin attack. I've defeated the goblin attacks myself several times and I know that there exists a NPC **Goblin Thief**. Can this thief steal from us? Even from chests?

Or am I being kept in dark while one of the players swindled the coins?

Comment: i think you got robbed, in my experience as a server host, never trust your attendees.

Comment: Writing a batch script to save a separate copy of "worlds" folder in my documents every 10 minutes @Paralytic ~_~ Will have to set up a password too.

Comment: had people hack my accounts just to give themselves items. then deny it completely event though I keep auto logs for all my servers.

Comment: Try using a piggy bank or a safe. Those keep your hard-earned gold pieces from being stolen, as only you can access their contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the Goblin Thief does not steal anything from chests, despite his name.

Sources:

- http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goblin_Thief
- http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Goblin_Thief